# "Precondition" vs. "prerequisite"

Tags: differences, nouns, meaning-in-context

> In conclusion, security is the precondition of political freedom and political freedom is the prerequisite for economic freedom.

Do *precondition* and *prerequisite* mean the same in the above? Is there a difference?

Comment: What’s an above? :)

Answer (score 4):

They do appear to mean the same thing.  With apologies for borrowing from the usage of `precondition` in computer programming, there may be a slight difference.

A precondition must be 'true' for the ensuing process, but may not be a process in itself.  A prerequisite, on the other hand, is a process by itself that must have been achieved and completed before the next process starts.

In the example you cite, the precondition must be true but is not necessarily a completed process or it may have other co-requisite ingredients or conditions.  The latter part of the sentence is definitely more definite.

Hoping that it makes some sense!

Comment: “A prerequisite, on the other hand, is a process by itself” is incorrect, or at least misleading.  For example, in  “A million-dollar bond is prerequisite for bidding”, the “million-dollar bond” is a condition, not a process as such.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible the speech writer /author just want to use a different word instead of repeating the same word. It may be a "distinction without a difference."